# power shell list files with (1) or (2) or (3)

Tags: powershell

I would like to list all files using PowerShell the name of the file has (1) or (2) or (3) at the end of the file name. I prefer to use the filter option for that

I try using this command

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'E:\' -Filter "*(*)" -Recurse -Directory).Fullname
```

the problem that it will get all files with the number inside brackets not (1) or (2) or (3)

can someone help to give me the right command

Comment: The example provided will not return files at all, only directories. The filter you used doesn't show as you intended, I think. Please review the code you posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PowerShell allows [wildcards and also ranges](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_wildcards?view=powershell-5.1) in file/path names.

If you are after `files` don't forget the extension

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $ENV:USERPROFILE -Include '*([1-3]).*' -Recurse
```

Sample run here returns:

```
    Directory: C:\Users\LotPings\OneDrive\Pictures\Screenshots

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----

-a---l       2017-07-23     19:29        (52696) 2017-07-23 (3).png
-a---l       2018-06-16     13:59        (50499) 2018-06-16 (1).png
```